# dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Tags: dpkg

i am getting an dpkg error while installing eclipse...

```
sanju@sanju-HP-000-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install eclipse
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

how i fix this error..
plz guys help me..

Comment: See that part where it tells you what to do to correct the problem? Try running that. If it doesn't work, post the output so we can figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I got this just today. Didn't you just interrupted an installation like I did? Just run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in your terminal and finish the rest of the installation.

Comment: thanks brother for answering my question but i have did this no. of times but didn't work on terminal